process.env in catalyst functions:shell command does not picks up the configured environment variables from the Zoho Catalyst console
I have configured environment variables in the development environment. When i run the catalyst functions:shell to execute my event function, i am not able to retrieve the values through process.env in my nodejs function.
How to retrieve the environment variables inside the function?

You have to configure your environment variables in your local machine in order to retrieve it through process.env in your nodejs function while running the Catalyst function in in your local by using the catalyst serve or by using the functions:shell command.
You can set the env variables in your environment management files and it can be any of these such as .bashrc,.profile,.zprofile etc according to your machine.
